# Упорядочить массив методом бинарной вставки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Нужна помощь в алгоритме. Как собственно упорядочить массив методом бинарной вставки?

Comment: А что вам непонятно? Какое-то место в описании алгоритма? Реализация?

Comment: @Rikaz  Метод бинарной вставки - это метод сортировки массива?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видимо речь идет о [сортировке вставками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8).

В С++ сортировка вставками делается при помощи двух стандартных алгоритмов - `std::upper_bound` и `std::rotate`.

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
void insertion_sort(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
  for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
    auto insert_to = std::upper_bound(first, it, *it);
    std::rotate(insert_to, it, std::next(it));
  }
}
```

`it` указывает на текущий элемент.
`upper_bound` делает бинарный поиск в диапазоне `[first; it)`, и находит позицию для вставки `it`.
`rotate` проворачивает диапазон `[insert_to; it]`, перемещая элемент в позиции `it` на место `insert_to`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i:= 2 to n do
    if a[i-1]>a[i] then
  begin x:= a[i];
    left:= 1;
    right:= n-1;
    repeat
      sred:= (left+right) div 2;
      if a[sred]<x then left:= sred+1
            else right:= sred-1;
        until left>right;
    for j:= i-1 downto left do a[j+1]:= a[j];
    a[left]:= x;
 end;
```